# If the corporation is worthless, are short sellers still legally required to cover their positions?

Tags: stocks, shorting-securities

Consider the following hypothetical scenario:

Let's imagine I spent $X billion buying up all of the shares of a well-known-and-failing public firm (listed on the NYSE or NASDAQ) and then demanded that all short sellers cover their positions by purchasing shares from me at an absurd price (say, $50 million per share).

What would happen in this scenario? The price I am asking is utterly ridiculous when compared to the underlying "nearly worthless" book price. Is there a maximum price I can demand? Or am I free to make the price as exorbitant as I please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your second paragraph, Sure.  In the spirit of your question, yes, that's a short squeeze.

Regarding your third paragraph. This seems to be the key to this interesting hypothetical question.

What happens if parties **literally** can noit close out a short, for some extreme hypothetical reason?  So, you're forced to buy but there just literally is not a share for sale.

(In your extreme example, because "someone bought every one and they are not selling!")

Note that, anything you google on this will just be people giving the answer "it's unlikely that would happen in the real world".

In my opinion / guess, the various relevant regulatory bodies probably ***have not specifically addressed this*** (because it is "so hypothetical").

The only way we could find that out is by asking a real insider legal expert at the SEC or such.  (And they would likely just answer "it's unlikely that would happen in the real world".)

But here's a simpler answer and what would *actually happen*:

don't forget everything ***is just a contract.***

Say we have a contract that you have to give me $8,000 (because of a sale of a car, some engineering work or whatever). Say you don't give it to me.  Say you can't give it to me because of death, total loss of assets, or whatever.

What happens?  Well, nothing happens - I get screwed.  Maybe, someone has to declare bankruptcy.

(It's worth noting on the options front, they're called "contracts" because they're just .. contracts.  Contracts of all type get busted every day of the week.)

Shit happens - not even 15 years ago there was a thing where major brokerages went bust.  What happened?  Some government printed money to keep things relatively smooth.

So yeah, IMO your ultra-hypothetical would indeed result in a breakdown/loss.

Some parties would be off the hook (which is no more remarkable than when someone simply goes bankrupt after partying with their Visa at Chanel) or there would be a force majeure act by gov'mint. (Someone would just declare that so and so, has to pay so much, to so and so - and that's the end of it.)

Again, in my guess: the various relevant regulatory bodies probably ***have not specifically addressed this*** (because it is "so hypothetical") so even if we could dig up a "Nasdaq lawyer" she'd probably say it's unaddressed specifically (and then point out "it's unlikely that would happen in the real world".)

It could be there's some vague get-out-of-jail force majeure language in the relevant legal bedrock - which is always thrown in to cover hyptheticals like this.

Answer (score 2):

The good news is that with a public float of 307 millions shares, at the current price, all of the outstanding shares would cost you under $60 million.  The bad news is that that's not how the market works.  It's an auction.  The more shares that you buy, the higher the price goes, perhaps exacerbated by some short sellers covering.  So the premise of buying all of the shares for $100 million is likely to be farfetched.

As for your premise. if you  buy a lot of JC Penney shares, you can demand anything that you want but you can't directly force short sellers to do anything. Here are the mechanics of shorting:

- (A) owns the stock
- (B) borrows the stock from (A) via his broker and sells it to (C).
- (A) has book entry ownership of the shares but the actual shares are in (C)’s account.
- There are no restrictions on (A). He can sell his shares at any time. When he does that, (A)'s broker requests that (B)'s broker return the shares.
- (B)'s broker will then borrow the shares from another in house account that owns these shares. If there are none, (B)'s broker will try to borrow them from another broker so that (B) can remain short.
- If the stock is hard to borrow and none can be borrowed,(B) will receive a forced buy-in notice and he will have until 4 PM EST to cover his short position.

In order to force short sellers to cover, your going to have to buy enough shares so that none are borrowable and offer a high enough price so that the long owners (A)'s decide to sell.

Your premise is possible but it's not as easy as just plunking down  $100 million for all of the outstanding shares.  My guess is that you'll have to have much deeper pockets.  And all of this assumes that the company remains viable.  If something blows up the recent bankruptcy court settlement, you're the last bagholder before JCP disappears into the ether.  Wave goodbye to your $100 million or whatever the number is.